# Combining rows without a unique ID

Tags: r

I have a dataset where data on the same plant was collected on different dates. I want it so that plant_height, gall_diameter, and gall_height are on the same row for the same plant but this requires grouping by multiple columns and I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is a subset of the dataset:

````
structure(list(Date = c("7/16/21", "7/16/21", "7/16/21", "7/14/21", 
"7/14/21", "7/14/21"), Rep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Footprint = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Treatment = c("s_ambient", "s_ambient", 
"s_ambient", "s_ambient", "s_ambient", "s_ambient"), Plant_Num = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Gall_Present = c("gall", "gall", "gall", 
"gall", "gall", "gall"), Plant_Height = c(NA, NA, NA, 46.3, 56.5, 
66.4), Gall_Diameter = c(5.6, 4.1, 5.6, NA, NA, NA), Gall_Height = c(5.9, 
3.7, 2.6, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data follows the same structure across the whole set, you could pick out `Plant_Height` and create a temporary data set without missing values, and then join into the main dataset, also omitting missing values.

```r
library(dplyr)

df_ph <- df %>% select(Plant_Num, Plant_Height) %>% 
  na.omit()

#>   Plant_Num Plant_Height
#> 4         1         46.3
#> 5         2         56.5
#> 6         3         66.4

df_res <- df %>% select(-Plant_Height) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  full_join(df_ph)

#> Joining, by = "Plant_Num"
#>      Date Rep Footprint Treatment Plant_Num Gall_Present Gall_Diameter
#> 1 7/16/21   1         1 s_ambient         1         gall           5.6
#> 2 7/16/21   1         1 s_ambient         2         gall           4.1
#> 3 7/16/21   1         1 s_ambient         3         gall           5.6
#>   Gall_Height Plant_Height
#> 1         5.9         46.3
#> 2         3.7         56.5
#> 3         2.6         66.4
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is triggered because you have different `Date` values for the same `Plant_Num`, i.e. `Plant_Num` = 1 has two values for `Date`, "7/16/21" and "7/14/21". The first has values for `Gall_Diameter` and `Gall_Height` but not for `Plant_Height`. It is the opposite for the latter.

To merge these lines you will have to set a common `Date` value or, as proposed below, remove the `Date` column at least for the time of cleaning `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  group_by(Rep, Treatment, Plant_Num, Gall_Present) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), na.omit)) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Output:

```
   Rep Treatment Plant_Num Gall_Present Plant_Height Gall_Diameter Gall_Height
  <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>               <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 s_ambient         1 gall                 46.3           5.6         5.9
2     1 s_ambient         2 gall                 56.5           4.1         3.7
3     1 s_ambient         3 gall                 66.4           5.6         2.6
```

If you want to `Date` column back afterwards, just make a `*_join()` with the original dataset:

```
 df %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  group_by(Rep, Treatment, Plant_Num, Gall_Present) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), na.omit)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  right_join(., select(df, c("Date", "Plant_Num")), by = "Plant_Num")

    Rep Treatment Plant_Num Gall_Present Footprint Plant_Height Gall_Diameter Gall_Height Date   
  <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>            <int>        <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 s_ambient         1 gall                 1         46.3           5.6         5.9 7/16/21
2     1 s_ambient         1 gall                 1         46.3           5.6         5.9 7/14/21
3     1 s_ambient         2 gall                 1         56.5           4.1         3.7 7/16/21
4     1 s_ambient         2 gall                 1         56.5           4.1         3.7 7/14/21
5     1 s_ambient         3 gall                 1         66.4           5.6         2.6 7/16/21
6     1 s_ambient         3 gall                 1         66.4           5.6         2.6 7/14/21
```